# Eat lunch or have lunch

Tags: grammar

Yesterday, one of my friend updated his status *Eating lunch at a hotel*.
I thought that *Having lunch at a hotel* is correct.

So, I did a quick search on Google and got mixed responses.
Google fetched about 15,90,00,000 results for *eat lunch*. While, for *have lunch*, it fetched around 42,50,00,000 results.
From these results, it is sure that both are used. But, Is it correct?
Can one eat lunch? Because, lunch is not food itself, one cannot eat it.

Comment: For a more serious search try Google Books, nGrams, COCA and BNC. https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22eat+lunch%22&tbm=bks https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=eat+lunch&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ceat%20lunch%3B%2Cc0 http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/x3.asp?xx=1&w10=eat&w11=lunch&r= http://bnc.bl.uk/saraWeb.php?qy=eat+lunch&mysubmit=Go

Comment: Lunch is a meal, it consists of food, and we eat food. The verb, *have*, allows us to say we consumed both solids and liquids. We don't normally say "**I ate milk and biscuits for breakfast**" but "**I had milk and biscuits for breakfast**".

Comment: @Kris: Your third link is not working. I am getting session expired error.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I too find that's so. Try entering the phrase "eat lunch" in http://corpus.byu.edu/coca  (Thereafter, the link works -- not sure why.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can one eat lunch? Because, lunch is not food itself, one cannot eat it.

I think lunch does not *only* refer to the time one eats the food, it can certainly refer to the food. And [merriam-webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lunch) agrees with me:

> **1**:  a usually light meal; especially :  one taken in the middle of the day
>   **2**:  the food prepared for a lunch

So, analogous to *meal*, *breakfast*, *dinner*, on can certainly *have* it and *eat* it.

In contrast, this doesn't work with [cake](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/you-can't-have-your-cake-and-eat-it-too):

> You can't have your cake and eat it.

It seems that with meals, which we can have, the meaning has shifted (or grown) to include also the specific *food* to be served at the meal, and because of that, we can also *eat* a meal. But food can be either *had* or *eaten*, where *having* the food does *not* imply eating it. So the extension of meaning only works in one direction, from meal to food, and not from food to meal. That said, on can order a steak by saying *I'll have the steak, please*, but strictly speaking, the fact that you probably intend to *eat* it once they give it to you is only *implied*.

Comment: Am confused. So, which one is proper in this case? Eating lunch at a hotel or Having lunch at a hotel.

Comment: For ordering, I'll also say *I'll have one steak, please*.

Comment: @Rohith: **Both** are correct! There is not always “just one right way” to say something :)

Answer (score 0):

I think we can say eating food instead of eating lunch and having lunch is correct
 I eat my lunch, I eat my dinner, and I sometimes remember to eat breakfast. is correct.(I'm having lunch but I'm not eating it.) "Having lunch" may be an occasion. "Let's have lunch."
"Let's eat lunch" might be used when the food is "at hand" but no one is eating.

Comment: So, you are saying that having lunch means, a person have the lunch with him/her, and that person may or may-not be eating it.

Comment: burm1 is onto something here. `Eating lunch` means specifically putting food into your mouth and chewing, whereas `having lunch` can include the table conversation, catching up one the news etc.